# Jupyter kernel dying when reading parquet files from multiple folders into sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, pyarrow

I am trying to read a very large amount of data from s3 parquet files into my SageMaker notebook instance. I am not sure how much data is too much data for the jupyter notebook to handle, so when I try a few files at once by providing a folder with many parquet files at once, the kernel dies. Is there anyway to proceed, given that I need to load even more data to train ML models later?

So far I tried a couple of different methods suggested here in StackOverflow, but since I am extremely new to AWS environment it has been hard to work things out by myself. Right now, the following code is what I am running:

```py
import s3fs
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# Creating an S3 Filesystem (Only required when using S3)

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
s3_path = "s3://my_bucket_name"
directory = 'path/to/folder'
print(f'{s3_path}/{directory}')

# Loading Files (S3)

data = pq.ParquetDataset(f'{s3_path}/{directory}', filesystem = s3, validate_schema=False).read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

I had a bunch of errors trying to read parquet files like these but now it seems to be working when I try to read just one file. How should I proceed?

Comment: When it succeeds reading in every single file only at once and then fails only when you load many of them, this clearly sounds like you have too few memory available.

Comment: Sure, but is there a suggestion as to what I should do? Is there a way to extract only a sample when reading from parquet into the jupyter (sagemaker) environment?

Comment: In my experience pyarrow does not behave well under memory pressure and crashes like you experience. I try to avoid it if I can.

Last time we talked to our Sagemaker reps they mentioned a new functionality for reading Spark parquet data in Sagemaker notebooks. You might ask them about that, but I haven't seen any sign of it yet.